# ctime returns NULL randomly

Tags: c, datetime

I am using ctime. However it always returns NULL. So it cores on sprintf line. It worked earlier. So not sure why it is randomly returning NULL?

I have the following code snippet:

```
int main()
{
    char avp_val[50];

    uint32_t date_value=1477069401;

    sprintf(avp_val,"%s",ctime((time_t*)(&date_value)));

    return;
}
```

Comment: Why the blazes are you using a `uint32_t` instead of a `time_t`?  If you used the correct (and probably 64-bit) type, you wouldn't need the ugly and unreliable cast either, would you?  Oh, and `return;` instead of `return 0;` is another mistake — you must return a value.

Comment: You might want to move the `ctime` call to a separate line. That way you can check the return value from `ctime`, and make sure it succeeded, before passing the result to `sprintf`.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. i am reading bytes from a pkt . SO i read 4 bytes that represent this date  and need to convert to a human readable format. This was jyst a test program so didnt care abt the return; :)

Comment: @Gauri, well, then **don't cast the pointers**, first cast the data to a true `time_t` and then you'll be able to use the reference without problems (with independence of if it came from a data packet or whatever).  Casting a pointer to data only makes things more confusing, because the compiler looses the type information it had before, so type checking ceases to work.

Answer (score 5):

Don't cast a pointer to `uint32_t` to a `time_t`. Use an actual `time_t`, so on systems with 64 bit `time_t` `ctime` isn't reading four bytes of garbage as part of the epoch time:

```
int main()
{
    char avp_val[50];

    time_t date_value=1477069401;

    sprintf(avp_val,"%s",ctime(&date_value));
    // Or, because it's what you're doing anyway, skip sprintf:
    // strcpy(avp_val, ctime(&date_value));

    return 0;
}
```

Casting to `(time_t*)` to silence compiler warnings silenced the warnings, it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: And, @Gauri , just to be clear: the warning that you get without the cast is the warning that tells you that you have a problem!  ctime is returning NULL because it's expecting a pointer to an 8-byte time_t, but you're passing a pointer to a 4-byte uint32_t.

Comment: @SteveSummit: Well, the `NULL` from `ctime` isn't because it recognizes you passed it a pointer to the wrong type. It's because the four extra bytes it reads, while technically readable (if they weren't, you'd seg fault), have junk values. `ctime` explodes when it realizes the date represented by that timestamp occurs in the year 212,321,423,324 CE (arbitrarily chosen from the range of values a 64 bit `time_t` could represent). `ctime` has a Y10K problem. :-)

Comment: i changed my code to:  time_t now = (time_t) date_value; sprintf(avp_val,"%s",ctime(&now)); and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Well, your code lacks a bunch of include files:

```
#include <stdlib.h>  /* for the types you use below, like uint32_t */
#include <stdio.h>  /* for a prototype for sprintf, which you use below */
#include <time.h> /* for a prototype for ctime() see NOTE 1 */
```

You must also take into account that casting must be done with data values, not with pointers, as casting a pointer only bypasses the compiler type checking system and makes your code more error prone.  In this case you conversion from `uint32_t *` to `time_t *` is too dangerous if both types happen to have different sizes, as you'll be cutting the value using only half the bits required.  This is something knows as Undefined Behaviour and you should avoid it.

You also have to return an explicit value from main.  It's a compile error not to do so, so your example cannot execute, because it does not compile (and so, you cannot receive `NULL` from `ctime(3)`)

By the way, I tried your code with `uint32_t date_value` in a mac OS/X  and it printed the right value of time, so probably `time_t` is a 32 bit value, but you had better to use a `time_t` as it is defined by that reason.

## NOTE 1

The most important in this case is the prototype of ctime(), which returns a pointer to `char` and without a prototype, the compiler assumes it returns an `int`.  At least, in 64bit platforms, both types are different sizes, and cannot be passed this way.

Please, always post a [Complete, minimum, verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, as you can hide the exact source of the error by editing your example to be shown.